# Use of simple statistics for matched study designs

Tags: logistic, anova, t-test, matching, case-control-study

This might be a silly question, but I have always found this confusing. In a case-control study one selects participants to the study based on having or not having the outcome, in addition to some set of matching factors. Matching on its own does not eliminate confounding by the matched factors, and in fact can induce confounding in some setting. Thus, a matched design requires controlling for the matching factors in the analysis, either through simple adjustment or by using a conditional analysis (see https://www.bmj.com/content/352/bmj.i969 for a more extended discussion of this).

Does this mean that given a matched design, one cannot use simple statistics such as a T-test/Anova to compare the different outcome groups, since such methods do not allow for adjusting for the matching factors? Or can such simple statistical tests still be used to validly compare e.g. the mean, but it is when we move to providing an estimate of the effect measure (e.g. a risk or odds ratio) that we have to start worring about those additional required adjustments?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that given a matched design, one cannot use simple statistics such as a T-test/Anova to compare the different outcome groups, since such methods do not allow for adjusting for the matching factors?

Well, a twin design is the perfect example of a matched design not requiring adjustment for the matching factor!

In matching - which mind you is different from a case control study - we often adjust for a matching factor for two reasons.

1. Residual confounding - in quasiexperimental designs, we might create "blocks" by age intervals of 10 or 5 years, but as you know a 69 year old is different from a 60 year old by quite a bit.
2. Prognostic value - blocking can remove confounding, but it does not stratify the effect estimates, you can still adjust for the factor and significantly reduce the residual standard error. In fact, a blocked design can *increase* the residual standard error relative to simple random sampling because you oversample heterogeneous groups!

None of any of this applies if there's undetected interactions between factors!

A case control study is not a matched study, you're not forced to select a number of cases equal to a number of controls to ensure valid design or inference. You can sample controls in a ratio of 1:1, 2:1, 10:1, or in any fashion *as long as it doesn't depend on the covariates at all*. The power of logistic regression is that the effect estimate, the odds ratio, does not depend on the background frequency of the event and is thus consistent with measurements from longitudinal studies (i.e. where outcome dependent sampling has *not* occurred). Add to that, in the situation where the event is rare, the odds ratio approximates the risk ratio in a prospective design (another term for a study where outcome dependent sampling has *not* occurred).

Matching in case control designs still begs for adjustment due to the same reasons above.